# How to retrieve the index of data for the defaultCollapseIcon in MUI tree?

Tags: material-ui, tree

**TreeView**

```
<TreeView
        multiSelect
        defaultCollapseIcon={
          <ArrowDropDownIcon
            fontSize="large"
            onClick={e => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              setExpanded([]);
            }}
          />
        }
        defaultExpandIcon={
          <ArrowRightIcon
            fontSize="large"
            onClick={e => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              setExpanded(allIds);
            }}
          />
        }
        onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
        expanded={expanded}
      >
        {chain(data)
          .map(node => {
            if (node.count > 0) {
              return renderTree(node);
            }
            return null;
          })
          .value()}
      </TreeView>
```

**renderTree**

```
      key={nodes.id}
      nodeId={nodes.id}
      onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        clickCheck(event, nodes.children, nodes.id);
      }}
      label={
        <>
          <Checkbox
            checked={checkedStatus(nodes.children, nodes.id) === 'checked'}
            indeterminate={
              checkedStatus(nodes.children, nodes.id) === 'indeterminate'
            }
            tabIndex={-1}
            disableRipple
            onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
              clickCheck(event, nodes.children, nodes.id);
            }}
          />
          {nodes.name}
        </>
      }
    >
      {nodes.children.map(node => renderTree(node))}
    </TreeItem>
```

The intended behavior is that I would like the checkbox to be checked when clicking on the TreeItem or checkbox itself, and only when clicking on the icon should the collapsing effect occur.

If there's only one record, this effect works as expected. However, when there are two or more records, an anomaly occurs.

So, I hope to have the index available in the onClick events of the ArrowDropDownIcon and ArrowRightIcon. This way, it should work properly.